# Download a file from a webpage based on the file saved date

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am still very new at web development, I need some suggestions please. I am busy creating a page with a date selector, then I have a folder with one file saved every day. What I am trying to do is: The user needs to select the date of the file he wants and click download and the file saved on that date needs to be downloaded. Can someone please give me an idea how I can get this to work. I have tried some things with JavaScript and php and could not get a working solution.

Comment: You could just list all available dates and have the user click the one they want. http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the job.
First we scan path provided and list all files, then check creation date and find our target file.

```
<?php

$Path       = './'; // Set path of files here
$TargetDate = '2016-08-11'; // We find the first file with thi date
$TargetFile = null; // Store result here

// Lets Do It

foreach (glob("$Path/*") as $File) {
    $Stat = stat($File);

    if (date("Y-m-d", $Stat['ctime']) == $TargetDate) {
        $TargetFile = $File;
        break;
    }
}

// Your File!
if (is_null($TargetFile)) {
    echo 'No file found';
} else {
    echo $TargetFile;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you just saved me hours.. This works perfectly I just added a line in order to not just show the path but open the file.

Comment: Glad to help you <3